# My instance is not updating in my while loop

Tags: python

I want to recalculate the hash by changing the nonce by 1. but the instance of self.hash is not changing.

I am not that experienced and do not know how to fix these types of issues

```
import hashlib

class Block:

  def __init__(self, timestamp, transaction, previousHash = ''):
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.transaction = transaction
    self.nonce = 0
    self.previousHash = previousHash
    self.hash = self.calculateHash()

  def mineBlock(self):
    checkIfTrue = str(self.hash).startswith('0')
    while checkIfTrue != True:
        self.nonce += 1
        self.hash = self.calculateHash()
        print(self.hash)

    print("block mined")

  def calculateHash(self):
    h = hashlib.sha256((str(self.timestamp) + str(self.transaction) + str(self.previousHash) + str(self.nonce)).encode('utf-8'))
    return h.hexdigest()
```

Comment: One thing you will need to do is update `checkIfTrue` inside your while loop.  Currently, if the loop is entered it will never leave

Comment: that worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine for me, self.hash changes. But the program gets stuck in an infinite loop because the condition "while checkIfTrue != True:" does not change once inside the loop. Once you update the self.hash, you need to get out of the loop and do the "checkIfTrue = str(self.hash).startswith('0')" again.

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating `checkIfTrue` inside the loop.

There's no real need for that variable, just put the hash check in the `while` statement.

```
while not str(self.hash).startswith('0'):
    self.nonce += 1
    self.hash = self.calculateHash()
    print(self.hash)
```